# JointPlot in seaborn

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

My code-

```
num=[5,4,3,2,4,6,7,8,9]
df = pd.DataFrame({'abc':num})
da = seaborn.jointplot('abc', 'abc', data=df, kind="kde", space = 0.1, color="r", height=12)
```

This shows the error in numpy.linalg.linalgerror: singular matrix

If, I use the default kind argument, it works fine. But not for "kde".

And, I used the python interpreter to code, seaborn latest version 0.10.0

This code works fine in Google colab but not in python interpreter

Error Log-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py", line 2321, in jointplot
    grid.plot_joint(kdeplot, **joint_kws)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py", line 1785, in plot_joint
    func(self.x, self.y, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.py", line 701, in kdeplot
    cbar, cbar_ax, cbar_kws, ax, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.py", line 407, in _bivariate_kdeplot
    xx, yy, z = _scipy_bivariate_kde(x, y, bw, gridsize, cut, clip)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.py", line 488, in _scipy_bivariate_kde
    kde = stats.gaussian_kde(data.T, bw_method=bw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/kde.py", line 209, in __init__self.set_bandwidth(bw_method=bw_method)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/kde.py", line 565, in set_bandwidth
    self._compute_covariance()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/kde.py", line 577, in _compute_covariance
    self._data_inv_cov = linalg.inv(self._data_covariance)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/linalg/basic.py", line 979, in inv
    raise LinAlgError("singular matrix")
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: singular matrix
```

Any suggestion... thanks

Comment: Code works fine and plots it in python interpreter. Could you please provide the error log?

Comment: Maybe upgrading the latest seaborn version could help?

Comment: @Ehsan, I included the error

Comment: @JohanC, I am using the latest version

Comment: Try updating your NumPy and SciPy too. I even tried it with `seaborn.kdeplot` and it works fine. Probably somewhere in kde calculation it faces a singular matrix which newer versions might have dealt with it. I looked at spicy source code and the latest version is different than your error message.

Comment: @Ehsan, Numpy and scipy is also the latest version, but got the same error